# Chrome headless auto restart listener after crash

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, headless, puppeteer

I am looking for a solution to **auto restart chrome** in node JS with puppeteer api:

something like:

```
browser.on('error', (err: Error) => {
  // do restart
})
```

I didn't found in documentation a way to have a listener if something wrong or error is handled.

Someone have a solution ?

Thanks you !

Max

Answer (score 3):

You could use a process manager like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to restart your app when it crashes.

With pm2 you can:

```
pm2 start myApp.js
```

Then it will auto restart the app if it crashes.

You could also use the `--watch` flag to restart the app when a file changes.

```
pm2 start myApp.js --watch
```